# Whats is the best practice for setting images dynamically in an android app?

Tags: android, image, dynamic, nine-patch

I have created an android app that pulls graphics from the server (9patch png) to create the users gui. (If at this point of my question someone already has a suggestion for a best practice. Please share with me)

Now im trying to make the app work in different screen sizes so I have created appropriate files for every screen size.
Now the question:
Should I send to the server the screen size and get the appropriate image or is there a way to pull  all the images from the server and make android pick the right one?

The issue is mainly about the jpgs (backgrounds) as im using 9patch pngs for the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you must do this, you should definitely request the correctly sized image from the server only.

Not doing this would potentially require the app to download an image for every size bucket, thats up to 5 and probably at least 3 from ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi. Full screen images at full resolution are usually >1mb and hence this would be slow and data intensive.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Square's [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library.  You could use one image and resize it via picasso, or have multiple images stored at different url's and just provide the url you need based on the device.  Picasso manages a cache memory , disk , network. so you would effectively have the correctly sized file cached on each device.  I am not sure if the cached file is the transformed file or the raw file, if it were the transformed file you may only need one file on the server since it will only be downloaded rarely.